# Loading image of another imageview in anothe imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two ImageView. in one ImageView I'm Loading image. and i have another ImageView.

I need to show image of onther imageView in different imageView.

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
```

i have GridView in that i'm setting multiple images in "imgview" object.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        txtinfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, status));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                ImageView imgview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
                ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
                imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_checked);
                // imgview1.setImageBitmap( i have to load image of imageview object);
            }
        });
}
```

Please help me out.. Thanks..

Comment: Can't see any reasons for a downvote!

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgview);
ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
imgview.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_box_checked);
bitmap b = BitmapFactry.decodeResource(your resource, your ID);
imageView1.setimageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(imgview, position); imgview1.setImageBitmap(b);

Comment: giving error : The method decodeResource(Resources, int) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView, int)

Comment: Or otherwise try imageView1.setimageResource(imageView.getId());

Comment: now error is resolved, but after clicking on image. its not loading image in imageView.

Comment: i have created image resourse in another class ImageAdapter.   private int[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.video_photo, R.drawable.video_photo,
   R.drawable.video_photo, R.drawable.video_photo,
   R.drawable.video_photo, };

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to extract the bitmap:

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
```

and then import the bitmap:

```
imageView1.setimageBitmap(bmap);
```

Comment: after clicking on grid view it is loading null image in imageView.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ImageView grid_item_image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
         grid_item_image.buildDrawingCache();

 Bitmap bmap = grid_item_image.getDrawingCache();

ivLogoDialog = (ImageView)dialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.ivLogoDialog);

 ivLogoDialog.setImageBitmap(bmap);
```

Comment: I am using the image of gridview and adding it to custom dialog box imageview i.e ivLogoDialog